# IOS navigationController?.popToRootViewController has wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

```
@IBAction func addInformation(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // check rateHourly has value
    if let editedRateHourly = rateHourly.text {
        print("editedRateHourly condition is \(editedRateHourly)")
        if editedRateHourly != ""{
            print("not nil")
            // check edit value is number?
            let num = Int(editedRateHourly)
            if num != nil {
                print("is num")
                // add to database
                UserDefaults.standard.set(editedRateHourly, forKey: "\(findDate())")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                // back to last viewController
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            }else{
                print("not num")
                print("error alert push!!")
                popErrorAlert()
            }
        }else {
            print("nil")
            print("editedRateHourly condition is nil")
            popErrorAlert()
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func cannelInformationPage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

I want to create a new simple edit page. It's two problem for me that when I finish edition if-else will check the condition is correct or not and then save the data popToRootViewControlle. When I finish edition I click on "addInformation" BarButtonItem and I get UI wrong. the Other wrong is when I click on editField but I don't enter any condition. And then I click on "cannelInformationPage" UIBarButtonItem. It also get wrong.

[It's what I get wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2tmE.png)

[wrong information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTttq.png)

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean under **I get UI wrong**?
If you roor controller should display updated information from UserDefaults then you should manually refresh it e.g on viewWillAppear

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2tmE.png
I mean when I click the "cannelInformationPage" or "addInformation".the code should be run "navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)".but it push the wrong

Comment: Did your  app crashed ? According to attached image, your app crashed due to some reasons and not wrong UI.

Comment: @Chien-anLin could you show error from debug terminal? On image there is only part of stack trace

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTttq.png I get this wrong message

Comment: I have a feeling that you have an `IBOutlet/IBAction` that is not tagged correctly in your `ViewController` that's why it crashes

Answer (score 1):

Because it returns Bool

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you want to come back to last view controller than you can try above line, hope its work for you.

Comment: I try add self, but it doesn't work. If I take off all the if-else,it can work

Comment: Have you try popViewController(animated: true) ?

Comment: You need to go back to View Controller when you pressed to UIBarButtonItem?
Then you must try ,

@IBAction func cannelInformationPage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    _ =  navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}

Comment: Please check  that @IBAction method is properly connnected or not?